# Spring cloud server prefix cause error 404

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-cloud

I have Spring cloud server that configured as follows:

```
# Spring
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/data/config/
spring.jmx.default-domain=${spring.application.name}
endpoints.jmx.domain=${spring.application.name}
endpoints.jmx.unique-names=true
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.profiles.include=prod,machine
info.app.name=${spring.application.name}
spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=1

# Config server
ms-configuration.config.path=/data/config/
ms-configuration.profile.default=prod
ms-configuration.backup.fullPath=/home/afa/msConfigBackup.zip

# Logging
logging.file=/data/algosec-ms/logs/${spring.application.name}.log

#Endpoints
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,backup,restore
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

And it works just fine.
I am trying to add new rest controllers for the server in order to support swagger.
Yet all the rest calls are automatically identified as configuration requests.
So I added to the application.properties file the prefix option:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/config
```

And now all the rest responses are

{"timestamp":"2020-01-09T11:31:22.063+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/ms-configuration/config"}

I have tried the following curls and got the same result.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/ms-configuration/config/swagger/

curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/ms-configuration/config/

curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/ms-configuration/config/app_a
```

What can I do in order to keep my Spring cloud server as a configuration server and also a rest API controller?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to change the prefix in the clients as well

Comment: Yes of course, but how is it solve the CURL issue?
I will still get 404

Comment: /config goes first

Comment: I don't understand.
Can u please elaborate?

I trying to call the config server using:
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/ms-configuration/config/
And I am getting 404 

How define the /config in the clients will help?

Comment: It is a prefix, no postfix. So you should add config after `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the curl to:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/config/ms-configuration/swagger/

curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/config/ms-configuration/

curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/config/ms-configuration/app_a
```

As the spring.cloud.config.server.prefix is a prefix which is added in front of the url. (assuming you do not have a context path)